# Why is the output to this code both 2?

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation

```
public class Bird
{
private static int id = 0;
private String kind;
public Bird(String requiredKind)
{
    id = id + 1;
    kind = requiredKind;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Kind: " + kind + ", Id: " + id + "; ";
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Bird [] birds = new Bird[2];
    birds[0] = new Bird("falcon");
    birds[1] = new Bird("eagle");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        System.out.print(birds[i]);
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

I understand that because int is static both id's will be the same but can't figure out why the output is 2 instead of 1?

Output when run:

```
Kind: falcon, Id: 2; Kind: eagle, Id: 2;
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a static variable..shared by all object instances. You created two objects, thus incrementing twice through the constructor.. to be honest I can't see what more I can add to the answer.

```
   //where [x] denotes id:
    First instance: id = [0] + 1; //id is 1 
    Second instance id = [1] + 1 // id is 2
```

Um.. if you want to have a unique id, you can have one extra field that is unique to an object, I think this should solve your problem:

```
private int Id; 
private static int tracker;
public Bird()
{
    //keep track of object instances, yet each increment is unique to a particular 
    //object
   Id = ++tracker; 
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for all the answers

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` is `static`, its shared by all the instances of `Bird`. You created 2 objects, and `id` was incremented twice, therefore, `2` was printed when you tried to print `id` for each `Bird` instance.

Answer (score 0):

`static` variables shared by all the created object, it is initialized once, so it will not going to initialize each and every time you create a new object.

As initial value of id is 0 and you have created two new objects. So the value will be incremented twice and the new value will be 2.